# How to change values in a column based on cell values in another column in excel?

Tags: excel

I read about `if` condition but apparently it only applies to `single cell` of `two columns`. I was wondering if there is way to modify the entire column based on cell values from another column. For example

```
=================            ================
       A                           B
=================            ================
     France                     Hong Kong
     USA                        New York
     China                      Hong Kong
     China                      New York
```

I want cell values in col **A** to change based on col **B**, so *France becomes China in row 1* and *China becomes USA in row 4* and so on. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: you can try a simple trick  by storing Column B data and corresponding column A values in list and then do comparison by looping i+2 , as next values is of column A stored. 
compare column B data to list values if Matched(suppose at position n) then update column A to N+1 list values....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a table in Sheet2 as follows.

```
=================  ================
       A                   B
=================  ================
      Delhi              India
      New York           USA
      Hong Kong          China
```

Then in first sheet use the following formula.

=INDIRECT( "Sheet2!B" & MATCH(A1, Sheet2!A:A, 0) )

Answer (score 0):

You need to have table or array i.e. 2 columns. Then use this table/array in vlookup Refer [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).